# Autocomplete with field related to ContentType

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I need some help with an issue that I am not able to resolve on my own.
So in this model, a tenancy document can either have a ForeignKey with building or property.

I can't figure out how to add autocomplete fields to contenttype and in the dropdown, I just see building and property in admin form. I want to see building names and property names.

I  learned about autocomplete fields in Django 2.0, it's awesome but I don't know how can I use something like that in this particular case or if there is a better way to do this?

Model:

```
class TenancyDocument(models.Model):

    KINDS = Choices('Tenancy Agreement', 'Stamp Duty', 'Inventory List')

    id = FlaxId(primary_key=True)
    kind = StatusField(choices_name='KINDS')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    content_type_limit = Q(
        app_label='properties', model='building') | Q(
            app_label='properties', model='property')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        limit_choices_to=content_type_limit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Lease type'
        )

    object_id = FlaxId(blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.kind
```

Admin:

```
@admin.register(TenancyDocument)
class TenancyDocumnentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'kind', 'start_date', 'end_date','content_type')
    list_filter = ('kind',)
```